# How can I pass logfile location to an IErrorHandler?

Tags: .net, ierrorhandler

I've got a C# Windows Service hosting a WCF Service (two separate projects).  My WCF Service project implements `IErrorHandler`, which I'd like to use to log errors to a file.  My Windows Service is doing some logging to a file, and I'd like my `IErrorHandler` to write to that same file.

How can I accomplish this (without hardcoding the filename in `IErrorHandler`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new static class with a public static filepath property 
In that class, load the filepath to the log file from the windows service app.config.
Then also reference that class from your WCF service and you should be able to use the same value stored in the public static filepath property.

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help.